# can anyone understand the problem from the photos? Kotlin android studio

Tags: kotlin

I ruined everything trying to create a new project. The same error occurred in my previous projects. It was finished and working. I'm new and I don't know much. Please explain simply. The problem is in the photos.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw3xK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5lZA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRazN.png)

I explained my problem and I am waiting for a  solution.

Comment: Try to click Sync now in the build.gradle app

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

add build.gradle (module)

```
buildFeatures{
  dataBinding true
  viewBinding true
}
```

and sync the project

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work